# I'm getting a NoMethodError on rails, unsure how to access a model through another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

Im writing a game on rails, and am trying to allow a user to create their mine (its a mining game).
I have a table for the users, and a table for mines.
Each user has a ref. ID on their entry, pointing to their mine's ID in the mine table.

I'm getting an error when I try to visit /users/1/mines/new.

> undefined method `mines_path'

I can't figure out why.

form in New:

```
<%= form_for [@mine] do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %><br>

    <p>Depth: <%= @mine.depth %></p>

    <%= f.submit "Submit", id: "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def new
 @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
 @mine = @user.mines.new
end

def create
 @mine = @user.mines.create(mine_params)
 if @mine.save
  redirect_to users_mines_path
 else
  render new_mines_path
 end
end
```

routes:

```
root 'welcome#index'
resources :sessions, only: [:create]
resources :users do
  resources :mines
end
resources :tools, only: [:create]
```

How can I create a new mine THROUGH the user? Am I doing this correctly in my controller?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes you have mines nested inside users so you need to change your form to something like this:

```
<%= form_for [@user,@mine] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br>

  <p>Depth: <%= @mine.depth %></p>

  <%= f.submit "Submit", id: "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

**OR**

You can specify url option with your path:

```
<%= form_for @mine, url: user_mines_path(@user)  do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br>

  <p>Depth: <%= @mine.depth %></p>

  <%= f.submit "Submit", id: "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

For details on forms refer to [`Form Helpers`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

Also as `@Vimsha` pointed out in your controller you need to use .new instead of .create as create will initialize and save your your mine.

```
def create
  @mine = @user.mines.new(mine_params)
  if @mine.save
    redirect_to user_mines_path
  else
    render new_user_mine_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `@user.mines.create` will create the mine. So use `@user.mines.new`
2. named route for mine index will be `user_mines_path`
3. named route for mine show will be `user_mine_path(@mine)`
4. named route for new mine will be `new_user_mine_path`

Contoller:

```
def create
  @mine = @user.mines.new(mine_params)
  if @mine.save
     redirect_to user_mines_path
  else
     render new_user_mine_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Im still getting the error: undefined method mines_path. 
   Again, heres how my form looks:
   
`<div class="new-mine-form">`
     `<%= form_for @mine do |f| %>`
      `<%= f.label :name %>`
      `<%= f.text_field :name %><br>`
Do I not use @mine in the form?